# Vb.net fill 2 textbox with same db id but different information

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows form with 2 textboxes, with a database in the back. I would like to fill information based on id number. The information has multiple events for the same id. I get it to fill the first textbox based on information, but how do I past to next id info for the second textbox

```
Dim cmd As oleDbCommand = New oleDbCommand("SELECT * from tblEvent WHERE id = '" & label1.Text &"' ", con) 
con.open
Dim reader As oledDbDataReader =  cmd.ExecuteReader 
If (reader.Read()=True)
TxtInfo1.Text=reader.Item("tblEvent")
End if
```

This works to fill the one textbox for the first event, but how do I continue to the next textbox with next event?

Comment: Have you tried doing anything with TxtInfo2.Text in your If/Then statement?

Comment: How many records does your query return?  If you are expecting two records, then just read again and fill out the second textbox.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Comment: at the very least you should able to just do a reader.read() prior to the next textbox. This would move the cursor to the next record in the results of the query. But yea, first and foremost, parameterize your statements for security purposes. If there is a lot of rows returned, consider a list type control to view your results. Nothing says you can't have a datagridview with a single column.